# COUNT to return NULL as 0 in same table in SAS PROC SQL with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, count, null, sas, left-join

I am having a task where I have 1 table. There is a unique ID for transactions, transaction dates, and store names.
My task would be to count the number of transactions every store made during March.

This, in itself, is simple:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE marchtransactions AS SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(tr_id) , store_name
FROM transactions
WHERE MONTH(tr_date)=3
GROUP BY store_name;
quit;
```

This would lead to a table where a store is present only if it had a transaction in March.
If a store does not have a transaction, it would be a NULL, and therefore, it will not be presented in the table at all.

While technically the task is fine as it is, I would really like to present every store in my table, even those who made no transaction in March.
So I want to see the 0 count values as well.

I have seen many different scenarios on the internet: IFNULL function, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, etc., but this is only one table, and in SAS PROC SQL, there is no such thing as IFNULL.

I have tried something like making a helper table with the store names and use LEFT JOIN as well, but I had no success. I even tried using CASE WHEN, with no success at all (keep in mind, I am quite a beginner, I may have done one of these things wrong though) :(

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: If this is just one table of transactions and there is no table of stores, how do you know what stores exist? Your table only list stores that have had at least one transaction at some time.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, but certain stores may have had transactions in other months but not in March.

Comment: It would be better to have a different source of `store_name`, because according to its name `transactions` table will most likely be the largest one, so it would be better to filter it by period. In case of March of some year, not all Marches, you may consider `tr_date between date '2021-03-01' and date '2021-03-31'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS a boolean expression is evaluated as 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE).  So to "count" how many times a condition happens just SUM() the condition.

```
proc sql;
  CREATE TABLE marchtransactions AS
    SELECT store_name, sum(MONTH(tr_date)=3) as march_count
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY store_name
  ;
quit;
```

If you have to do the same thing in some other SQL implementation just use a CASE clause.

```
sum(case when (MONTH(tr_date)=3) then 1 else 0 end) as march_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't restrict this to month 3 rows. Look at all rows, but only *count* month 3. (And remove that superfluous `DISTINCT` please.)

```
SELECT
  store_name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(tr_date) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS in_march
FROM transactions
GROUP BY store_name
ORDER BY store_name;
```

This is called conditional aggregation by the way (using `CASE WHEN` or `FILTER` in aggregations).